# Processing of group policy failed - Only on 32bit machines

Tags: windows, active-directory, group-policy, wmi

When forcing a group policy update I get the following messgae, but only on 32bit windows machines. 64bit works fine. Running windows 7.

The processing of Group Policy failed. Windows could not evaluate the Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI) filter for the Group Policy object (GPO) %8. This could be caused by RSoP being disabled or Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI) service being disabled or stopped, or other WMI errors.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd392547%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Comment: So, the error message raises the question: are you using WMI filters on the GPO?

Comment: Good thinking, but no WMI filters

Comment: Is this happening for all group policy objects, or just a specific one?  Try putting a computer in a test OU with only a single, freshly created empty GPO and see what happens.

Comment: The error implies WMI filters in use. Can you pleae confirm that WMI itself is working on the affected machines. Some command like "wmic os get name" will confirm if WMI is OK.